# I think I experienced an audit bug while reviewing

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, review-suspension

I was becoming acquainted with the review process, and I believe I experienced a bug. I had failed some of the audits and then I came across a post that was spam and accidentally clicked 'needs editing' and it told me I had failed an audit. I reviewed some more questions and everything was ok.

I then left my computer on the same review page for a few hours while cooking dinner and whatnot and came back and finished reviewing the post I was on. I clicked my choice and then it told me the post was obviously spam and I should return in 7 days to continue reviewing.

It was right in the fact that I did fail that particular audit, but the post it was quoting was not the post that I had just reviewed... I clicked back and got to the last post that I had reviewed and was still able to see it. I posted screenshots of the pages that I was seeing when the error happened.

[image: Post I was reviewing]

[image: Post that was linked after I successfully reviewed a "good post"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no bug here. Between the time you loaded the review item, then went off to your own things, then came back and completed that review item, a moderator had manually review banned you for the action you took on that previous review item. That meant you were no longer eligible to review and attempting to review the item you had already loaded failed. Instead, you were taken to the message given by the moderator.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the answer